# Gui glitching vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-glitch, trouble-tickets

When using vs code suddenly I started having glitch issues with the program. I am using ubuntu 18.04 and installed via snap. All 3 demonstrate glitches: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU1tI.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmS0L.png) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSGOg.png)

Additionally nothing shows inside the taskbars now, possibly to do with disabling hardware acceleration? I can't remember well enough if that was an issue before. I tried
code --disable-gpu

I have also run on windows 10 without issues, although I have other issues that rarely  relate to cpu overheating.

via terminal to disable hardware acceleration. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling via snap but issues persisted.

Version: 1.82.1
Commit: 6509174151d557a81c9d0b5f8a5a1e9274db5585
Date: 2023-09-08T08:41:36.199Z
Electron: 25.8.0
ElectronBuildId: 23503258
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.4.0-162-generic snap

Comment: cannot reproduce on Ubuntu 22.04.2. I suggest you also raise an issue ticket. If you do, please add a link to it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem just now, they released a new version yesterday it seems. Reverting VSCode to the release before that solved it for me.

If you've installed via snap try `snap revert code` since snap retains the last version(s) even though the channel gets overridden - although I do not know how snap handles your reinstallation and if the old version is still maintained.

Ubuntu: 20.04.6 
VSCode (after reverting): 1.82.0 (Commit 8b617bd08fd9e3fc94d14adb8d358b56e3f72314)

*Edit to clarify:*

To install older versions in snap you usually use channels. For the vscode snaps you do not have said channels for old releases. As a quickfix you can still use the `revert` command IF you have previous versions stored by snap ([Check this answer on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1373424)).

If you did a complete fresh install you might not have previous snaps - in that case `snap revert` will most likely not work. Using an alternative installation option *might* be the solution for you (didn't test it since `snap revert` sufficed for me). One option might be to

- download the `.deb` package you need [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_81)
- install it using `apt` as explained [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)

Comment: give exact version numbers. Also, what OS are you on and what desktop environment?

Comment: I tried reverting but received: "error: cannot revert "code": no revision to revert to". [Given that you can only add a channel. How did this work for you?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268615/snap-install-specific-old-version)

Comment: @Renanin that is probably due to your uninstalling and reinstalling of VSCode (deleting your old versions previously retained by snap). I guess I would just try to install directly via `apt` for now or report the bug and wait for a fix to be applied to the snap on their *stable* channel. I updated my answer for a few more resources.

Comment: I downloaded 1.84 version on Nov 16th and it was still having issue, I had to install 1.80 stable version from June month. Atleast this question and answer helped me to know I am not alone with this issue !